# Set HDFS replication factor while running S3DistCp

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce, emr

I am using [S3DistCp](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html) to copy content from S3 to Amazon EMR HDFS. For some jobs I am running out of space and expect to solve this issue by reducing replication factor. But I do not see way to achieve this at job level. Can someone help on this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would not normally want to modify a cluster's **replication factor** on a job-by-job basis. Replication is used for data redundancy (in case of failure) and to improve performance (by having data closer to the compute operations). It's best to leave the cluster at a pre-defined value.

By default, Amazon EMR sets the default replication factor to 1 for 1-3 core nodes, the value to 2 for 4-9 core nodes, and the value to 3 for 10+ core nodes.

You could theoretically change the `dfs.replication` setting, but it's probably not the best way to solve your current problem.

Comment: Let me give you some more context. Most of my jobs uses S3 buckets as source of data. For those job we do not want to waste space in HDFS by setting replication factor more than 1. But there are some other jobs uses HDFS as primary source of data and we need redundancy. I am not sure if there is any clear solution to this, but just want to put this question out there to get suggestions. Thank you for your help

Comment: I've found some references that say "block size and replication factor are configurable per file", but I'm not clear on how it is done. I wonder if this could be incorporated as part of the S3DistCp, on a per-file basis rather than a cluster-wide basis?